# Extract Public Key from the public certificate (.der / .cer)

Tags: x509certificate

I am trying to wrap a generated symmetric key using the public key which i want to extract it from the Public Certificate(.der / .cer ) when i am passing the public key for wrapping the symmetric key i am getting an "java.security.InvalidKeyException" exception "**Only keys that exist in 'RAW' format are supported**"

When i am loading the public certificate using file input stream as

**publicCertificate = new X509Certificate(new FileInputStream("src/resources/mydomain.com.der"));**

for extracting the publicKey i am using this getPublicKey(); method

publicKey = publicCertificate.getPublicKey();

I am such exception when i extracted the public key and it is in the X.509 format which i need to convert it into RAW format.

Can anyone please help me out here.

Thanks in Advance.